# XML-Any: Unmarshalling from Soap not working

Tags: java, xml, web-services, soap

I have a soap-service which has an XML-type Parameter (HeaderType) - which works fine... This type has an Object-List with any xml types (HeaderType -> ObjectType -> ApplicationCustomType -> List any). One of those types could be a 'SignatureType' - but unmarshaling (@WebParam) is not working and I get only a Node for this subtype (when I create a new JAB-Context with package-classloader it works).

```
@XmlAnyElement(lax = true) 
protected List<Object> any; 

for (Object obj : headerType.getObject().getApplicatoinCustom().getAny()) {
  if obj instanceof SignatureType) {
```

*Probably there is something wrong with the namespaces - but I couldn't figure it out so far.*

I made a small working example on Git: https://github.com/beatjost/xml-any

As it's a spring boot application, just run as java application from eclipse (after gradle build). A soap-ui project is in the root Folder. The service is in class 'XmlService'. (Response should be: [1]... instead of [2]...)

**Do you have any hints what is wrong with my XML-Type, ObjectFactory or Namespace... How do I need to configure this that unmarshalling works with paramter root-type 'HeaderType'?**  --> See class 'XmlService'